# Search ot string in a array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function in javascript, which finds a string in a text and prints how many times the string is found in the text. Here is my code, It's not working for some reason.... Please help

```
var word = 'text',
    text = 'This is some wierd stupid text to show you the stupid text without meaning text just wierd text oh text stupid text without meaning.';

searchWord(word, text);

function searchWord(word, text) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 1: console.log('Invalid input, please try again'); break;
        case 2: var array = text.split(' ');
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var count = 0;
                if (array[i] === word) {
                    count ++;
                }
            }
            console.log('Word ' + word + ' is repeated in the text ' + count + ' times');

    }
}
```

Comment: accept an answer, that has resolved your problem by Clicking on Check Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small problem in your code. You have to move

```
var count = 0;
```

outside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
  var count = 0;
```

Outside your loop

Answer (score 2):

Your `count` variable should be outside of your `for loop`, else you are resetting it everytime you enter the loop.

```
function searchWord(word, text) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
        case 1: console.log('Invalid input, please try again'); break;
        case 2: var array = text.split(' ');
            var count = 0;//Place it here.
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                if (array[i] === word) {
                    count ++;
                }
            }
            console.log('Word ' + word + ' is repeated in the text ' + count + ' times');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a regular expression to count the occurences

```js
var word = 'text',
    text = 'This is some wierd stupid text to show you the stupid text without meaning text just wierd text oh text stupid text without meaning.';

searchWord(word, text);

function searchWord(word, text) {
    var re = new RegExp(""+text+"", "g");
    var count = (text.match(/text/g) || []).length;
    console.log('Word ' + word + ' is repeated in the text ' + count + ' times');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but this is a short version of getting the count:

```
function getWordCount(word, text) {
     if(arguments.length === 0) return;

     var count = 0;
     text.split(" ").forEach(function(val) {
          if(val === word) count++;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### A simple one line solution without loops or RegExp

This one line solution appears to work. Note that it appends a space to the head and tail of the sentence to catch matching words at ends. This could be done with a pure RegExp too, but then it wouldn't be one line ... and I like simple solutions.

```
return (' ' + text.toLowerCase() + ' ').split( ' ' + word.toLowerCase() + ' ' ).length - 1;
```

And refactoring the original code we can eliminate 10 extraneous lines and a loop:

```js
function searchWord(word, text) {
  return (' ' + text.toLowerCase() + ' ').split( ' ' + word.toLowerCase() + ' ' ).length - 1;
}

var word = 'text',
    text = 'This is some wierd stupid text to show you the stupid text without meaning text just wierd text oh text stupid text without meaning.';

console.log('Word ' + word + ' is repeated in the text ' + searchWord(word,text) + ' times');
```